# nginx unknown directive "ssl_certificate_by_lua_block" error

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I just installed [openresty](http://openresty.org/) 1.9.15.1 and want to try [`ssl_certificate_by_lua_block`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ssl_certificate_by_lua_block) directive.

But I got an error saying

> [emerg] 13854#0: unknown directive "ssl_certificate_by_lua_block" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

The error message is written to the error log when I reload nginx using `/etc/init.d/nginx reload`.

But one thing strange is that the console says `ok` with the reload operation.

```
Reloading nginx configuration nginx                                  [ OK ]
```

`nginx -t` says my nginx.conf syntax is ok.

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Part of my nginx.conf looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {
        print("About to initiate a new SSL handshake!")
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://$host$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com-443.log cloudwatch_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com-443.error ;
}
```

And here's the version of my nginx:

```
nginx -V
nginx version: openresty/1.9.15.1
built by gcc 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/local/openresty/nginx --with-debug --with-cc-opt='-DNGX_LUA_USE_ASSERT
-DNGX_LUA_ABORT_AT_PANIC -O2' --add-module=../ngx_devel_kit-0.3.0 --add-module=../echo-nginx-module-0.59
--add-module=../xss-nginx-module-0.05 --add-module=../ngx_coolkit-0.2rc3
--add-module=../set-misc-nginx-module-0.30 --add-module=../form-input-nginx-module-0.12
--add-module=../encrypted-session-nginx-module-0.05 --add-module=../ngx_postgres-1.0rc7
--add-module=../srcache-nginx-module-0.31 --add-module=../ngx_lua-0.10.5 --add-module=../ngx_lua_upstream-0.05
--add-module=../headers-more-nginx-module-0.30 --add-module=../array-var-nginx-module-0.05 
--add-module=../memc-nginx-module-0.17 --add-module=../redis2-nginx-module-0.13 
--add-module=../redis-nginx-module-0.3.7 --add-module=../rds-json-nginx-module-0.14 
--add-module=../rds-csv-nginx-module-0.07 --with-ld-opt=-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib 
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log 
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi 
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy 
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi 
--lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-sha1=/usr/include/openssl 
--with-md5=/usr/include/openssl --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-pcre-jit 
--with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_gunzip_module 
--with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_geoip_module 
--with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module 
--with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-stream --with-ipv6 --with-openssl=/root/openssl-1.0.2l
```

Is there anything wrong with my installation of openresty?

The [installation document](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#installation) says

> It is highly recommended to use OpenResty releases which integrate Nginx, ngx_lua, LuaJIT 2.1, as well as other powerful companion Nginx modules and Lua libraries.

That's why I think `ssl_certificate_by_lua_block` is available once openresty is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely you have two nginx versions installed and service is configured for original nginx.
You try to edit the nginx.conf file used by original nginx.

OpenResty version was built with `--prefix=/usr/local/openresty/nginx`

It means that OpenResty version by default will look for /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

For fast check - add ssl_certificate_by_lua_block (and others required) directive to this file and start OpenResty nginx:

```
sudo /usr/local/openresty/bin/openresty -g 'daemon off;'
```

It should work.

You will need to configure your nginx service to use OpenResty version instead of original one.